# Are there known vulnerabilities in JonDo's custom Tor client?

Tags: vulnerability, jondonym

The JonDo client includes an [option for accessing the Tor network](https://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/en/help/services_tor.html). Given some of the features (excerpted below) it seems to use a custom Tor client. Are there known vulnerabilities?

> JonDo has Tor support, but it is experimental. This is why we do not guarantee complete or flawless functionality. If you would like to use JonDo to access the Tor network, you will need to enter JonDo as a SOCKS (not as a HTTP/HTTPS) proxy in your browser.
>
> Activate
>   ...
>   Available Tor nodes
>   ...
>   Reload
>   ...
>   Preferences for anonymous routing
>        Minimum [Tor] nodes per connection
>        ...
>        Maximum [Tor] nodes per connection
>        ...
>        Change [Tor] route every x connections
>        ...
>        Create anonymous [Tor] route at startup
>        ...